# Cassandra data model for intersection of ranges

Tags: cassandra

Assume data with pk (text), start (int), end (int), extra_data(text).
Query is: given a pk (e.g. 'pk1') and a range (e.g [1000, 2000]), find all rows for 'pk1' which intersect that range. This (sql) logically translates to WHERE pk=pk1 AND end>=1000 AND start<=2000 (intersection condition)

Notice this is NOT the same as the more conventional query of:
all rows for pk1 where start>1000 and start<2000

If I define a table with end as part of the clustering key:

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
pk text,
start bigint,
end bigint,
extra_data text,
PRIMARY KEY ((pk), start, end)
)...
```

Then Cassandra does not allow the query:
`select * from test1 where pk='pk1' and start < 2000 and end > 1000;`
with `"Clustering column "end" cannot be restricted (preceding column "start" is restricted by a non-EQ relation)"`

Why does Cassandra not allow further filtering to limit ranged rows (forces to do this filter with results application-side).

A second try would be to remove 'end' from clustering columns:

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
pk text,
start bigint,
end bigint,
extra_data text,
PRIMARY KEY ((pk), start)
)...
```

Then Cassandra warns the query:
`select * from test1 where pk='pk1' and start < 2000 and end > 1000;`
with `"Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING"`

Here I would like to understand if I can safely add the ALLOW FILTERING and be assured Cassandra will perform the scan only of 'pk1'.

Using cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.3

Comment: based on the data model that you've posted, it appears that `chr` is your partition / primary key and not sure how you could leverage `pk` field/column without leveraging `ALLOW FILTERING` which is again bad as for the reasons mentioned in another response.

Comment: chr was an error, the field name is pk. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think you made the fatal mistake of designing your table first and then trying to adapt the application query to fit the table design.

In Cassandra data modelling, the primary principle is to always start by listing all your application queries THEN design a table for each of those application queries -- not the other way around.

Let's say I have an IoT use case where I have sensors collecting temperature readings once a day. If my application needs to retrieve the readings from the last 7 days from a sensor, the app query is:

> Get the temperature for the last 7 days for sensor X

Assuming today is October 25, a more SQL-like representation of this app query is:

```
SELECT temperature FROM table
  WHERE sensor = X
  AND reading_date >= 2022-10-18
  AND reading_date < 2022-10-25
```

This means that we need to design the table such that:

- it is partitioned by sensor, and
- the data is clustered by date.

The table schema would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE readings_by_sensor (
    sensor text,
    reading_date date,
    temp float,
    PRIMARY KEY (sensor, reading_date)
)
```

We can then perform a range query on the date:

```
SELECT temperature FROM readings_by_sensor
    WHERE sensor = ?
    AND reading_date >= 2022-10-18
    AND reading_date < 2022-10-25
```

You don't need two separate columns to represent the start and end range because. Cheers!

Comment: I have only a query in mind and I am looking how to model my table based on it. Not every use case is sensors with date. I query predefined ranges in the genome: find all ranges that intersect the range 1000-2000. So it's not value within a range query. I don't think your suggestion applies in this use case.